# What to do if go module is broken

Tags: go

As Node.js developer I am still new to Golang and struggling with the dependency management in Go. I am using Go 1.11 and applied `mod init` after importing all my dependencies. One of them is logrus which prevents me from compiling my go application.

**The problem:**

I believe that the problem is indeed inside of logrus, however I don't know how I could now get another (working) version of logrus, so that I can compile my application again.

```
/Users/redacted/Documents/redacted3/redacted2>Finished running tool: /usr/local/bin/go vet ./...
/Users/redacted/go/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.2.0/entry.go:51: undefined: Logger
/Users/redacted/go/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.2.0/entry.go:54: undefined: Fields
/Users/redacted/go/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.2.0/entry.go:61: undefined: Level
```

How can I get rid of these annoying kind of dependency issues?

**Relevant import:**

```
log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
```

Go.mod contains

```
github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.2.0
```

Comment: Could we see some code (like your imports) and maybe the `go.mod`?

Comment: Hi, You may find this [Go (golang) Modules - The Basics : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0EjcYaBm9A] interesting. Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I added the relevant import and go mod line. Since only logrus seems to cause trouble I only added this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to delete the module in my `/go/pkg/mod/github.com/...` path which fixed the issue. Appparently something gone wrong while creating the module or initially pulling the code from github.

Afterwards I `go get` my logrus lib again and it worked as intended.

Comment: I'm glad that you find the solution. Good luck.

Comment: I have encountered this problem today after new build (with another package: Gin). Your solution worked for me. Thankyou very much for the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

- I think the logrus module is fine , you just missing the "log.WithFields" definition. Please take a look to the documentation here : https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus . The code below works for me.
- The main.go file:

  ```
  //Source : https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus
  //logrus version : require github.com/sirupsen/logrus v.1.2.0
  //go version go1.11.2 linux/amd64


  package main

  import (
  //Go package
  "os"
  "fmt"
  log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
  )

  //Checking if the logout file exist
  //Just to show the Fatal tag.
  func Exists(name string) bool {
          _, err := os.Stat(name)
          return !os.IsNotExist(err)
  }


  func main() {
          fmt.Println("I'am the main here ... all begin ...") 

          log.WithFields(log.Fields{"main": "main process",}).Info("Initialization.")
          log.WithFields(log.Fields{"main": "...some codes....",}).Warn("Nothting here yet.")

          log.WithFields(log.Fields{"main":"main process",}).Info("It's done. Thanks.")

          //The check here (it's just for demo) so you can see the others tags
          if Exists("paht/to/mylogoutfile") == false {
                  log.WithFields(log.Fields{"main": "Checking logoutputfile path.",}).Fatal("Mising the Logout file.")
  }

          //fmt.Println("This is the end Thankyou for using this. :) ")
          }
  ```
- The go.mod file:

  ```
  module logrustest

  require github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.2.0 // indirect
  ```
- Output :
  [image]

Good luck :)

Comment: Indeed I am using it just like you, I still believe that I got a broken version of the code. I looked into the logrus package `../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.2.0:` here and just like the error indicates this package has NO type Logger defined. So how could I redownload the package/module which maybe fixes this? This folder does not contain a `Logger.go` file for some reason..